# How could you read only the numbers in a string like this: Mon, 05 Feb 2018 21:00:39 +0000

Tags: javascript

i have no idea. I dont know how to read it correctly, so it would be nice if someone would help as im pretty new to Javascript. it would be usefull if the numbers would be in a one variable, thank you!

Comment: This `Mon, 05 Feb 2018 21:00:39 ` must returns:  `052018210039`?

Comment: First, google how to use Regular Expressions to grab the numbers from a string. Then give it a shot. Then, if you run into trouble, come back to Stack Overflow and post your attempt and where you are running into trouble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP shows no effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to remove all characters that are not a number.

```js
var s = "Mon, 05 Feb 2018 21:00:39 +0000";
var nums = s.replace(/\D/g, "");

console.log(nums);
```